# category__not_in and id values from variable

Tags: categories, loop, wp-query, variables

How can I set the values for category__not_in from two variables. On my example I just hardcode the ID of each category to exclude, but... how can I pass these values from some variables ?

```
    $category_a = get_category_by_slug('fbrt');
    $category_b = get_category_by_slug('contact');

    $exclude = get_the_ID();
    global $wp_query;
    $exclude = $wp_query->post->ID;
    $args = array(
        'category_name' => 'olympic-physique',
        'category__not_in' => array(1, 2),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'title', 
        'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`get_category_by_slug()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug) returns a category object or `FALSE`:

```
$cat1 = get_category_by_slug( 'cata' );
print '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $cat1, TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';
```

*Result:*

```
stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 3
    [name] => Cat A
    [slug] => cata
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 3
    [taxonomy] => category
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 2
    [cat_ID] => 3
    [category_count] => 2
    [category_description] => 
    [cat_name] => Cat A
    [category_nicename] => cata
    [category_parent] => 0
)
```

So, to get an array of IDs just check if you get an object for each slug and add the `term_id` to the array:

```
$category__not_in = array();
$slugs            = array ( 'cata', 'catdoesnotexist' );
foreach ( $slugs as $slug )
{
    $cat = get_category_by_slug( $slug );
    $cat and $category__not_in[] = $cat->term_id;
}
$args = array (
    'category__not_in' => $category__not_in
);
```

Instead of hard coding the slugs in your script consider to add [term meta data](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46560/attaching-metadata-to-a-taxonomy-item) to the categories. You will need an additional query to find all needed terms, but your script stays reusable.

Answer (score 0):

just use this $arg.

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'olympic-physique',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array('fbrt','contact'),
        'include_children' => true,
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```